# Building a train model in r after split function

Tags: r

I am building a logistic regression to predict the most effective buyers and I have a data sheet and I was able to write a code till split function, however one of the column in data sheet is in a range like $100-$200 ,$200-$300 .How can I can assign a random numeric value and proceed further , below is the code for reference

```
file_data_0 = read.csv('......csv')

View(file_data_0)

file_data_0[file_data_0 == '?'] = NA

filter_data_1 = na.omit(file_data_0)

View(filter_data_1)

summary(filter_data_1)

unique(filter_data_1$spend)

table(filter_data_1$spend)

table(filter_data_1$spend)/nrow(filter_data_1)

class(filter_data_1)
```

## split the data into training and testing

```
library(caTools)

set.seed(64000)

split_data <- sample.split(filter_data_1$spend, SplitRatio = 0.75)

train_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split_data == TRUE)

test_data <- subset(filter_data_1, split_data == FALSE)

dim(train_data)

dim(test_data)

dim(filter_data_1)

class(filter_data_1$history_segment)

filter_data_1$history_segment = as.numeric(filter_data_1$history_segment)
```

### sample data sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjL6v.png)

Comment: Always use `dput`, rather than picture of your dataframe. `dput(data_frame_name)`

Comment: If your data is in categories, you can't change to continuous form, you can create dummies of these categories and work with them, use `model.matrix ` in case you want to convert it to dummies or you can search in stackoverflow, there are tons of ways to convert a category to a dummy, Always remember you will create only n-1 dummies, where is n is number of categories of a variable.

Comment: One option could be to split the column with values like `$200-$300` and drive 2 columns from it. say `min` and `max`.

Comment: Here is the sample data for your reference                                                 recency history_segment  Spent 
10        2) $100 - $200  0        
6        3) $200 - $350  0        
7        2) $100 - $200  0        
9        5) $500 - $750  3.25        
2        1) $0 - $100  442        
6        2) $100 - $200  29.99        
9        3) $200 - $350  32.17        
9        1) $0 - $100  32.17        
9        5) $500 - $750  29.99

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```r
#sample data
#I copied it from the attached image file but in future you should always share your data using 'dput(df)'
df <- data.frame(recency = c(10,6,7,9),
                 history_segment=c('2) $100 - $200', '3) $200 - $350', '2) $100 - $200', '5) $500 - $750'),
                 mens=c(1,1,0,1))

#little bit of data cleaning in 'history_segment' column
# otherwise accessing these variables for further processing would be another pain!
df$history_segment <- paste0("his_seg_", gsub("^\\d)|\\s|\\$", "", gsub("-", "_", df$history_segment)))

#dummy code 'history_segment' variable
library(psych)
df_new <- cbind(df[,names(df) != "history_segment"], dummy.code(df$history_segment))
```

Now you can use `df_new` as your main data instead of `df`

```
> df
  recency history_segment mens
1      10 his_seg_100_200    1
2       6 his_seg_200_350    1
3       7 his_seg_100_200    0
4       9 his_seg_500_750    1
> df_new
  recency mens his_seg_100_200 his_seg_200_350 his_seg_500_750
1      10    1               1               0               0
2       6    1               0               1               0
3       7    0               1               0               0
4       9    1               0               0               1
```